# Why do two of the three functions not delay?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have 3 settimeout functions in one function.
The one calling the fades() works fine, not the one with the comments surrounded.

This is what I wanted it to do: first, play the loading bar. Next, fade the bar out and show a button.
The load bar didn't quite work but after that a button should have toggle_visibility(), which would show it.

```
<script>
  function toggle_visibility(id) {
    var e = document.getElementById(id);
      if (e.style.display == 'block')
        e.style.display = 'none';
      else
        e.style.display = 'block';

   };

    function fades() {
     //problem settimeout
    setTimeout(function(){
      $('#button1').toggle_visibility();
     }, 5500);
     // end of problem
    setTimeout(function() {
      playDemo('disney', 2, disneyInterval);
    }, 1000);

    setTimeout(function() {
      $('#mydiv').fadeOut();
    }, 5000); 

   };

    setTimeout(function() {
      fades();
    }, 10);

</script>
```

Comment: `$('#button1').toggle_visibility();` has no parameter passed into the function. Which I'm guessing is why it doesn't work?

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#button1').toggle_visibility();
```

This code means function `toggle_visibility` is a function of jQuery. But in your code, it is just a function.

You can invoke it like `toggle_visibility('button1')`. This will change button1's display once.

Answer (score 0):

```
toggle_visibility(button1)
```

"toggle_visibility" is not a function for jquery! so $().toggle_visibility is undefined

Answer (score 0):

That's right guys. As was said before, here what you can do - implement this function to jQuery:

```
function toggle_visibility(id) {
    var e = $('#'+id);
    if (e.css('display') == 'block'){
        e.css('display', 'none');
    }
    else {
      e.css('display', 'block');
   }
}
jQuery.fn.toggle_visibility = function() {
    return toggle_visibility(this.attr('id'));
}
```

Now you can use it like you used)

Answer (score 0):

1) To verify whether your callback function is being called or not, you simply place a console.log inside it with something like "function XXX called".

2) The timing in setTimeout is not perfect. It guarantees that your function will not be called before that time you specified has passed but does *NOT* guarantee it to be *exactly* at the requested time.

So if you just say:

```
setTimeout(f2, 500);
setTimeout(f3, 600);
```

It does not guarantee that f3 will be called exactly 100ms after f2.

If you try to rely on this to run animations, they will not always be smooth.

If you need to "chain" calls, let each callback call the other.

```
setTimeout(function() {
    console.log("Function 1");
    // do stuff
    setTimeout(function() {
        console.log("Function 2");
        // do stuff
        setTimeout(function() {
            console.log("Function 3")
            // do stuff
        },0);
    }, 500);
}, 1000)
```

Nested callbacks are nasty to read/write though, so you can flatten it out

```
function f1() {
    console.log("Function 1");
    // do stuff
    setTimeout(f2, 500)
}

function f2() {
    console.log("Function 2");
    // do stuff
    setTimeout(f3, 1000)
}

function f3() {
    console.log("Function 3")
    // do stuff
}

setTimeout(f1, 1000)
```